# Weak convergence of the 4-th degree of a weak convergent sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, weak-convergence, optimal-control

Good day!

We solve an optimal control problem
$$
J(u) = \|y - y_d\|^2 \to \inf
$$
where $y$ is a solution of the PDE
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} + Ay = Bu.
$$
$A$ is a nonlinear operator,
$(Bu, v) = \int\limits_\Gamma \gamma u^4 v d\Gamma$,

$y \in L^2(0,T;V)$, $u \in L^\infty(\Gamma)$.

The set of admissible controls is
$$
U_{ad} = \{ u \,\, \colon \, 0 \leq u \leq M \}.
$$

Our goal is proving the solvability of the solution of the optimal control problem.

We consider a minimizing sequence $u_k$: $J(u_k) \to j = \inf J$.

Sinse $U_{ad}$ isn't compact we should use weak convergence.
Here we may suppose that $u \in L^2(\Gamma)$ because $L^\infty(\Gamma)$ isn't reflexive.
Thus, there exists a subsequence $u_k \in U_{ad}$ that converges *weakly* to $u \in U_{ad}$.

Next we should to pass to the limit in the equation so we need that $u_k^4 \to u^4$ weakly. But in the general case it isn't so.

How to prove the existence of optimal control?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can interprete $u^4$ as a new control, $\tilde u$, with constraints $0\le \tilde u \le M^{1/4}$. Then the operator $B$ becomes linear,
$$
B(u,v) =\int_\Gamma \gamma u^4 vd\gamma = \int_\Gamma\gamma\tilde u vd\gamma,
$$
which makes passing to the weak limit an easy task.

Comment: Thank you very much! But in this problem the integral $$\int_\Gamma \beta u v d\Gamma$$ is presented too in the operator $B$. I didn't mention about it because I thought that it isn't important.

Comment: Then $\tilde u = \gamma u^4 + \beta u$ should do the trick. Since $x\mapsto \gamma x^4 + \beta x$ is monotone on $[0,+\infty)$, there is still a one-to-one correspondence between $u$ and $\tilde u$.

Comment: The functional $\int_\Gamma \beta uv d\Gamma$ is applied to another function $v$, i.e. $v = (v_1, v_2)$.

Comment: Actually we have 2 equations
$dy_1/dt + A_1y_1 = B_1 u$, $dy_2/dt + A_2y_2 = B_2 u^4$ where $(B_1 u, v) = \int \beta u v$, $(B_2 u^4, v) = \int \gamma u^4 v$.